# JDBC: Alternative of statement.cancel() in Informix DB?

Tags: jdbc, informix

I want to cancel a JDBC call if it's taking too long to respond from Database server.

I have read [here](http://ict.udlap.mx/people/roberto/jdbcis341/docsAndothers/doc/release/program.fm10.html) Statement.cancel() is not supported by Informix driver.

So what will be the alternate of it?

How can I cancel a JDBC request that is executing on DB. The request is generated through a JSP page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to cancel some statement?

Information from your link is very old (1998). From this time there were many new versions of Informix JDBC driver. Simply download newest driver (for now it is 3.70JC1) read its [Release Notes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.relnotes.doc/notes/jdbc_370jc1/jdbcrel.htm) and try to cancel some statement.

You can find Informix JDBC drivers at: http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/search.jsp?go=y&rs=ifxjdbc